does the scale should change with the Page scale in react pdf
I am using pdf.js to show some pdf file with react project, actually using react-pdf which wrapped the pdf.js. Now I am using scale like this to zoom in or zoom out the pdf:
      <Page
        key={index + "@new-" + projAttribute.pdfScale}
        scale={projAttribute.pdfScale}
        className={styles.pdfPage}
        onLoad={handlePageChange}
        canvasRef={(element) => updateRefArray(index, element)}
        onChange={handlePageChange}
        onRenderSuccess={handlePageRenderSuccess}
        pageNumber={index}
        width={width}
      >
        {curPdfPosition && viewPort ? (
          <Highlight
            position={curPdfPosition}
            pageNumber={index}
            viewport={viewPort}
          ></Highlight>
        ) : (
          <div></div>
        )}
      </Page>

and this is how I get the viewport:
 React.useEffect(() => {
  setPageViewports(undefined);

  if (!pdf) {
    return;
  }

  (async () => {
    const pageNumbers = Array.from(new Array(pdf.numPages)).map(
      (_, index) => index + 1
    );

    const nextPageViewports = await asyncMap(
      pageNumbers,
      (pageNumber: number) =>
        pdf
          .getPage(pageNumber)
          .then((page) =>
            page.getViewport({ scale: projAttr.pdfScale || 1 })
          )
    );
    setPageViewports(nextPageViewports);
  })();
}, [pdf]);

should I change the viewport scale or keep it with the same with pdf scale(the pdf scale range is 0.1-6.0, and + or - 0.1 with each click) when zoom the pdf? or what value should I set with the  viewport scale?
